# Python read filenames and save in list

Tags: python-2.7

I need to read all files in a directory and save into list, then read list those files one by one.
I don't want to use external module like 'glob module'. So, trying through 2 different approach:

**First approach:**

```
import os 
file_list = os.listdir("jsons")

for files in file_list:
    data = open(files,"r")
```

output:

```
  ['A03DUrQz1BM9SQ2.json', 'A04D5V1u1BMxaV6.json', 'A0kxiHL81AN9pH5.json', 'A1Fxs5Ag1A8vuB5.json', 'A2Dsv7RE1BDqYt5.json', 'A2HkZPkn1BpvvG5.json']
```

but here issue is that filenames are saved in string format and not able to open this file as it read it with quotes ''.

**2nd approach:**

```
file_list = os.system("ls jsons/")
**print file_list.split()**
for files in file_list:
    data = open(files,"r")
    print data
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asn-1_q3.py", line 9, in <module>
    print file_list.split()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Here, it is saving as int and not able to split the file. 
How should I solve them ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `read` your file object and `os.path.join` the file name with the original directory name (or it will look for the files in the current directory):

```
import os
import os.path
file_list = os.listdir("jsons")

for file_name in file_list:
    with open(os.path.join("jsons", file_name), "r") as src_file:
        data = src_file.read()
        print(data)
```

Here's an example that uses generators to limit the amount of data in memory (vs loading all the data into an array):

```
import os
os.path

def all_file_content(directory_name):
    file_list = os.listdir(directory_name)
    for file_name in file_list:
        with open(os.path.join(directory_name, file_name), "r") as src_file:
            yield src_file.read()

for file_content in all_file_content("jsons"):
    print(file_content)
```

Comment: thank you. It worked out. Also,  Thanks for sharing another generator example. I am learning to use generator into the code wherever possible